# Induction Question: $7^n-6n-1=36m$

Tags: induction

---

In the end I get the following:
$$(7^n-6k-1)+6(7^k-1)$$
I tell myself that $(7^n-6k-1)$ is clearly divisible by $36$ by the initial proposition, and that $6(7^k-1)$ is divisible by $36$ because $7^k-1$ is divisible by $6$ by the initial proposition. I'm just simply wondering if I've made an error in $\color{green}{\text{my reasoning}}$, that's all.

---

$$\color{green}{WORK}$$

Allow me to put forth the proposition that $7^n-6n-1=36m$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Clearly this holds for $n=1$ as $36$ divides $0$. Now, let's say $n=k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k>1$, and let's just say it holds, namely

$$7^k=6k-1=36p$$

holds. We need to show that this proposition holds for $k+1$ though. Let's do that now. Immediately we notice that

$$7^{k+1}-6(k+1)-1$$

reduces in the following manner:

$$7\cdot 7^k-6k-6-1$$

$$\downarrow$$

$$(6+1)7^k-6k-6-1$$

$$\downarrow$$

$$6\cdot 7^k+7^k-6k-6-1$$

$$\downarrow$$

$$\underset{\color{fuchsia}{\diamond}}{(7^k-6k-1)}+\underset{\color{blue}{\diamond}}{6(7^k-1)}$$

Now, notice that $\color{fuchsia}{\diamond}$ is clearly divisible by $36$ by the initial proposition, and so is $\color{blue}{\diamond}$ since $7^k-1$ is divisible by $6$ through the same proposition. Thus, by the principle of **figuring-things-out-on-your-own-and-not-consulting-yahoo-answers-or-by-copying-your-friend's-answer**, namely the Principle of Mathematical Induction, we have that

$$7^n-6n-1=36m$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. $\square$

---

Comment: You have not given full detail, and presumably you mean $7^k-6k-1$, not $7^n-6k-1$. But the analysis is probably essentially correct. A full proof would have to be given if one is to judge whether it is correct.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct..

Comment: Whether or not the analysis is essentially correct, if the OP does not write it coherently, no good will come of it.

Comment: What are $m$, $n$, and $k$? What is the initial proposition? I removed a couple tags because this question does not relate to analysis.

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: It was taken directly out of a book titled "Elementary Analysis."

Comment: Check my language... It might be a bit sloppy...

Comment: Very bad beginning in the "work" part. You say "Assume $7^n-5n-1=6m$ $\dots$. You are supposed to prove this, not assume it. There are other issues, the logic is unclear. You are supposed to work from the fact about $k$ to the fact about $k+1$. Your presentation is backwards. Perhaps someone will rewrite it for you. If no one does for a while, and I can find the post, I will do it.

Comment: Damn... I thought I was so slick...

Comment: How about now Mr. @AndréNicolas?

Answer (score 3):

We prove by induction that $36$ divides $7^n-6n-1$ for every positive integer $n$.

The result holds at $n=1$, since $7^1-(6)(1)-1=0$, and $36$ divides $0$.

Suppose that the result holds when $n$ is the particular integer $k$. We will show that the result holds when $n=k+1$. So we need to show that $36$ divides $7^{k+1}-6(k+1)-1$.  We note, as you did, that $7^{k+1}=7\cdot 7^k=7^k+6\cdot 7^k$. Thus
$$7^{k+1}-6(k+1)-1=7^k-6k-1+6(7^k-1).\tag{1}$$
By the induction assumption, $36$ divides $7^k-6k-1$. Also, by the induction assumption, $6$ divides $7^k-6k-1$, and therefore $6$ divides $7^k-1$. Thus $36$ divides $6(7^k-1)$. It follows that $36$ divides the right-hand side of (1), and therefore $36$ divides the right-hand side. That is what we needed to show.

**Remark:** Please note that the **idea** of the proof is the same as yours. However, we argued **from** the induction assumption $7^k-6k-1$ is divisible by $36$  **to** the conclusion that $7^{k+1}-6(k+1)-1$ is divisible by $36$.

Comment: I see... I appreciate your answer...

Comment: You are welcome. I think you knew precisely what's going on. The only issue was the exposition. Students often argue "backwards," from a desired result to something true. **If** every step of the argument can be reversed (as in this case) then the argument can be turned into a correct proof. But reversibility has to be checked. And it is all too easy to slip in a non-reversible step, in which case the argument is unfixable.